# Is there a pyarrow equivalent of the chunksize argument in pandas.read_csv?

Tags: pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I am looking to process a large file(5 gb) in RAM but am getting an out of memory error. Is there a way to process the parquet file in chunks like there is in `pandas.read_csv`?

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

    def main():
        df = pq.read_table('./data/train.parquet').to_pandas()            

    main()
```

Comment: There is not yet, but there are issues open about adding this option. Note that memory use will be significantly improved in the upcoming 0.12 release

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not yet, but there are issues open about adding this option (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-3771, others). Note that memory use will be significantly improved in the upcoming 0.12 release.

In the meantime, you can use `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile` and its `read_row_group` method to read one row group at a time.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Can you advise on an alternative way to process such a large file? (without using a Spark framework)

Comment: I added a note to my answer to suggest using the `read_row_group` method of `ParquetFile`